# Display WooCommerce Custom Field in Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom field that is a checkbox, which appears on checkout. This is added via the official WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor plugin. I want to display the result of the field in the customer & admin order emails. 
I have had some success using the code below but only displays a 1 if checked, and nothing if unchecked.

Is there a way to display the question and then a 'Yes please' or 'No thank you' text?

This is what is printed to the email using print_r($fields) :

```
Array
(
    [Yes, I would like to receive updates from Rogue Resolutions] =>
uncheck-to-opt-out-of-receiving-our-quarterly-newsletter-neuroscience-matters_field
)
```

Thanks in advance

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3);

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['Yes, I would like to receive updates from Rogue Resolutions'] = 'uncheck-to-opt-out-of-receiving-our-quarterly-newsletter-neuroscience-matters_field';
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Can you include what the $fields array looks like?

Comment: Updated question with the output. Thanks